# regular expression dont allow partial matching

Tags: regex, match, partial

Okay, first off I have strained relationship with regex. I can usually manage to make it grab or validate the data I need. But now it really feels like I've hit the regex wall.

I have concatinated strings of userdata that I need to validate.
They look something like: `john|45|some|data|00111{more|data`
The `{more|data`-part should be able to happen 0 or more times, but if I just use `(regex)*`. Then if one part fails, the string is still partially matched. I want it to fail the match in this case.

**To simplify my case:** I want `foo`, `foobar`, `foobarbar` to validate. But `foobarcar` and `foobat` to fail the validation.

`foo(?:bar)*` Will match all (last 2 only partially)

...if at all possible I would like to keep the "dont capture" part (?:).

From what I can tell, the solution might be in LookAround, a DontAllowPartialMatches parameter in the code, or splitting the string and validating the parts individually...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly match the end of a string (or possibly line, depending on your dialect) using `$`:

```
foo(?:bar)*$
```

This will match foo, foobar, foobarbar, etc., but not foobarcar or foobat, as you wanted.

(It will also match barfoobar, though, so if that's a problem, you'll probably want to use `^` to match the start explicitly too. `^foo(?:bar)*$`)

Comment: Oh, that simple huh... I was definately overestimating the problem then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regular expressions tend to have that effect on people.